# .ClassNotFoundException Spring Boot 2.0.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm new to spring and I'm trying to initialize a spring project using spring-boot 2.0.0 from https://start.spring.io/ with web as the dependencies.

it generates this pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kkesley</groupId>
    <artifactId>springtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springtest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and there's a main class

```
package com.kkesley.springtest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringtestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringtestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The application looks simple but I cannot seem to run it. I used `mvnw spring-boot:run` in the project's root and got this

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< com.kkesley:springtest >-----------------------
[INFO] Building springtest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ springtest >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ springtest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ springtest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ springtest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\kkesley\eclipse-workspace\springtest\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @
springtest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ springtest <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ springtest ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.kkesley.springtest.SpringtestApplication.main (SpringtestApplication.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.kkesley.springtest.SpringtestApplication.main (SpringtestApplication.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.414 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-23T11:29:12+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project springtest: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

What's happening here? I just want to run the simple application.
Thanks!

Comment: the dependencies downloaded could be broken, delete dependencies under  .m2 folder then update maven to download  them again

Comment: @Charizard_11 yes that works! can you tell me why does it happen? I use maven from the start. So how could the repos in .m2 broken? Anyway, if you make this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: try **clean install** the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes maven dependencies not be downloaded correctly, in these situations you should delete related dependencies under .m2 folder then update maven to download them again.